# Determine the origin of an Intent in a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-binder

I am looking for a way to determine what application sent an `Intent`. At present, I've registered a `BroadcastReceiver` and have been trying to work with `Binder.getCallingPid`, but it usually returns my app's PID. What I find weird is the usually part, my app does occasionally get the PID of the app that sent the `Intent`, but it's not often and I cannot seem to pin down the conditions for which this is true.

Is there a way to accurately determine what app initiated a call to `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive`?

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("Receiver", "Sender's PID: " + Binder.getCallingPid());
}
```

Comment: Are you using the local broadcast receiver?

Comment: No, the idea is to register the receiver with the system (Context.registerReceiver) and determine which app sends Intents I'm listening for.

Comment: Thats good because it would never leave your app, Whats your manifest entry look like?

Comment: It's not registered in my Manifest.xml, it's registered dynamically with an IntentFilter and Context.registerReceiver. I'm looking for a general solution though, so it shouldn't depend on what actions I'm registering for.